# Searching a column name across a database in oracle9i?

Tags: oracle9i

Is there a way to search to which table or tables a column(say Cycle_name) belongs to in oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * 
from all_tab_cols 
where column_name like '%%'
```

If you want also to spiecified a table add the following to WHERE clause

```
table_name like '%%'
```

Comment: Maybe it's permission problem, Try USER_TAB_COLS instead of all_tab_cols